# Python reading tempfile after creating with suffix option produces an error

Tags: python, windows, temporary-files

The following program:

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess
def os_read_binary_file(binary_data, original_file_name=None):
    suffix = None
    if original_file_name:
        suffix = os.path.splitext(original_file_name)[1]
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb", suffix=suffix) as f:
        f.write(binary_data)
        f.flush()
        file_path = f.name
        p = subprocess.check_output(["start", file_path], shell=True)

def read_file_to_bolb(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        bolb_data = file.read()
    return bolb_data

bin = read_file_to_bolb('./zxc.xlsx')
os_read_binary_file(bin, 'zxc.xlsx')
```

produces the error

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Environment:

```
Windows 10
Python 3.8.10
```

If I remove the suffix, the error doesn't appear, but the file doesn't open using its default extension.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: You need to close the context manager and release file lock before you start your file. Just move your `p = subprocess.check_output(["start", file_path], shell=True)` out of block (remove 1 tab) and it should work

Comment: Upd. I missed that you are using TemporaryFile which is being closed and deleted right after context is closed (as python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) state). You would want to use open() for this case

Comment: I am using check_output so that the file is deleted after the process of the OS that is reading the file is finished. This way I can have a simple context manager. 
I am wondering why the error is produced only when I add the suffix to opening the file, without the suffix argument the error doesn't seem to happen